# Loading design-time WPF resources in Visual Studio through .csproj

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, csproj, design-time-data

In Expression Blend 4, it's possible to load design-time resources by editing your project file. Here's an example of what that would look like:

```
<Page Include="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml"
    Condition="'$(DesignTime)'=='true'
    OR ('$(SolutionPath)'!='' AND Exists('$(SolutionPath)')
    AND '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'!='true'
    AND '$(BuildingInsideExpressionBlend)'!='true')">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
</Page>
```

Now I've been trying to get the same thing working in Visual Studio 2010 without success. Has anyone gotten design-time data to load like this in Visual Studio or is this feature only supported using Expression Blend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the use of [d:DesignData and d:DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839627.aspx). Here is an [example on Jag Reehal's blog using Blend and Visual Studio](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-use-designdata-to-populate-controls-with-design-time-data-in-silverlight-and-wpf/). And a [Microsoft Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823176.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Mark, you got me on the right track! I needed to bind my DataContext to a property, so I ended up doing this: `<d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="MyViewModel" Source="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ViewModelLocator, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"/>
    </d:DesignProperties.DataContext> `